# Como funciona a referência de variáveis não declaradas no PHP?

Tags: php, variáveis, referência

No PHP, segundo o manual, a referência de uma variável serve para uma variável apontar para o mesmo lugar em que a outra está na memória. Vi também que quando declaramos referênciamos a uma variável que não existe, ela é criada e definda para `NULL`.

Daí surgiu um questionamento.

Temos os seguintes códigos.

Nessa tentativa de atribuição abaixo, um erro de execução será gerado.

```
$a  = $b->b->c->d->e->f->g; 

/*
    Undefined variable 'a'
    Trying to get property of non-object (6 vezes)
*/


var_dump($a, $b); // resultado: NULL NULL
```

Agora, quando utilizamos o operador de atribuição por referência (`&`), nenhum erro é gerado,  e o objeto (que não existe) é magicamente criado.

```
$a  =& $b->b->c->d->e->f->g; 
var_dump($a);
/*
    a = NULL
*/


print_r($b);

/* 

stdClass Object
(
    [b] => stdClass Object
        (
            [c] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [d] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [e] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [f] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [g] => 
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)

*/
```

1. Gostaria de saber como isso funciona internamente, no interpretador
   do `PHP`.
2. É recomendado criar um objeto dentro do outro dessa forma (pois já vi isso sendo usado numa implementação de [**Dot Notation**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851590/array-set-value-using-dot-notation) para PHP, porém ao invés de um objeto, é usado um array)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Se você atribuir, passar ou retornar uma variável indefinida por
>   referência, ela irá ser criada.

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.references.whatdo.php

> Uma variável PHP é armazenada em um recipiente chamado de "zval".  Um
>   recipiente zval contém, além do tipo e valor da variável, dois bits
>   adicionais de informação.  O primeiro é chamado de "is_ref" e é um
>   valor booleano que indica se ou não a variável é parte de um "conjunto
>   de referência". Com este bit, o motor do PHP sabe como diferenciar
>   entre as variáveis normais e referências.
>
> Desde que o PHP começou a permitir referências a nível de usuário,
>   criada pelo operador `&`, o recipiente zval passou a ter um mecanismo
>   de contagem de referência interna para otimizar o uso de memória. 
>   Esta segunda parte de informação adicional, chamado "refcount", contém
>   quantos nomes de variáveis (também chamados de símbolos) apontam para
>   este recipiente zval.
>
> Todos os símbolos são armazenadas em uma tabela de símbolos, dos quais
>   há um por escopo. Há um espaço para o script principal (ou seja, a uma
>   requerida pelo navegador), bem como uma para cada função ou método.

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php

Sendo assim, quando uma variável é copiada `$a = $b`, o PHP usa internamente a referência até que a cópia `$a` seja modificada.

Portanto, você deve evitar criar variáveis através de referências sem necessidade, uma vez que não vai guardar seu estado em memória e aumenta a chance de erros de lógica difíceis de descobrir.