# Referencia de variavel

Tags: php, passagem-por-referência

Estou estudando PHP e me deparei com uma questão de variaveis por referencia e não entendi muito bem como ela se comporta.

```
function foo(&$var) {
   $var++;  
}
$a=5;
foo($a);
echo $a; // Retorna 6
```

Quando vi esta função eu pensei: "Ué, mas se eu fizer uma chamada normal com `return $var++` também vai funcionar...

```
function bar($var) {
   return $var++;
}
$b=5;
bar($b);
echo $b; // Retorna 5
```

Não consegui entender muito bem o comportamento e o porque da primeira função realizar o incremento e da segunda função não.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.references.pass.php

Comment: @Zoom a primeira coisa que eu fiz foi olhar na documentação e como não entendi resolvi perguntar para tentar achar a explicações em outras palavras.

Comment: Entendi, Mano. Beleza... ! Logo aparecerá uma boa resposta.

Comment: Pelo que você disse, você não entendeu bem o funcionamento do `return`, não das referências. O `return` é mais importante e útil de entender primeiro. Não adianta retornar "pra ninguém".

Comment: Relacionado http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48777/como-funciona-a-refer%C3%AAncia-de-vari%C3%A1veis-n%C3%A3o-declaradas-no-php

Comment: Essa tag também tem algo relacionado [passagem-por-referência](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/passagem-por-refer%c3%aancia)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Simplificando

Neste primeiro caso, acontece o seguinte:

```
function bar($var) {
   $var++;
   return $var;
}
$b = 5;
echo bar( $b ); // Mostra 6 - valor do return
echo $b;        // Mostra 5 - valor do $b
```

- é atríbuido `5` a `$b`.
- você chama a função `bar`, passando **o valor** `5` a ela.
- o valor `5` é guardado em `$var`, que é incrementada.
- você dá echo em `$b`, que nunca deixou de ser `5`.

Veja a diferença. Usei as mesmas variáveis que o caso anterior para simplificar:

```
function bar( &$var ) {
   $var++;
   return $var;
}
$b = 5;
echo bar( $b ); // Mostra 6 - valor do return
echo $b;        // Mostra 6 - valor do $b
```

- é atríbuido `5` a `$`b.
- você chama a função `bar`, passando **a variável `$b`** para ela.
  (isto acontece graças ao `&`, que pegou a **referência** e não o **valor**).
- `$b` é **a mesma coisa** que `$var`, e incrementado.
- você dá echo em `$b`, que foi incrementado dentro de `bar`
  (através do seu "nome alternativo" `$var`, que passou a ser o nome de `$b`na função).

Em resumo, no primeiro caso, `$var` é criado dentro da função com valor 5. No segundo caso, `$var` é `$b` com um nome novo.

### Complicando

Eu mudei os exemplos acima para usar as mesmas variáveis, e pus o incremento numa linha separada, para não cair nessa confusão:

```
function bar( &$var ) {
   return $var++;
}

$b = 5;
echo bar( $b ); // Mostra 5 - valor do return
echo $b;        // Mostra 6 - valor do $b
```

Notou algo estranho? É isso mesmo, veja no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/kD954Q)**.

O resultado estranho no primeiro `echo` não tem nada a ver com ser por referência ou não, e sim com o fato de estarmos incrementando `$var` DEPOIS do return. Se fosse `++$var`, as duas linhas mostrariam 6.

Apesar de não ser parte da pergunta, achei melhor comentar pois se a função da pergunta fosse testada com `echo` no retorno, poderia atrapalhar o entendimento.

Em resumo: neste caso, passamos `$b` para a função. Na função retornamos `$var`, que é o `$b` fora da função, ou seja, `5`. Depois do `return` é aplicado o `++`, que incrementou `$b` (chamado de `$var` dentro da função).

Answer (score 4):

A passagem por referencia creio ser uma das coisas mais legais que se tem na programação.
Creio que uma das perguntas que se deve fazer quando se estuda isso seja :

- Referencia para que?

#### Memoria

Imagine que quando você esta programando e faz uma atribuição a variavel : `$var = 5;`, 
você não esta simplesmente atribuindo 5 a uma variavel `$var`, você esta reservando um local 
na memoria de seu computador que tera como `alias` o nome `$var` e ele local vai possuir 
o valor 5.

```
 0050 | 0051 | 0052 | 0053 | 0054 | 0055 | 0056     <-- possição da memoria
      |      | $var |      |      |      |          <-- alias
      |      |   5  |      |      |      |          <-- valor/referencia
```

O alias na verdade é apenas um acesso para o conteudo da possição `0052` da memoria.

Quando você gera um passagem por referencia você esta dissendo que o conteudo daquela
possição de memoria não é um valor, mas uma referencia para um local que tem o valor.
É meio complicado mas seria basicamente assim :

```
$b = &$var;

 0050 | 0051 | 0052 | 0053 | 0054 | 0055 | 0056     <-- possição da memoria
      |      | $var |      |  $b  |      |          <-- alias
      |      |   5  |      | 0052 |      |          <-- valor/referencia
```

Agora quando você acessar `$b` eĺe não vai exibir `0052`, pois ele é um referencia, 
ele vai ate a referencia e pegar seu valor no caso `5`.

Dessa forma se o conteudo da possição `0052` for alterado tanto `$var` como `$b` serão 
alterados. Lembrando que você pode alteralo tanto por `$var` como por `$b`.

```
$var = 7;

 0050 | 0051 | 0052 | 0053 | 0054 | 0055 | 0056     <-- possição da memoria
      |      | $var |      |  $b  |      |          <-- alias
      |      |   7  |      | 0052 |      |          <-- valor/referencia

$b = 10;

 0050 | 0051 | 0052 | 0053 | 0054 | 0055 | 0056     <-- possição da memoria
      |      | $var |      |  $b  |      |          <-- alias
      |      |  10  |      | 0052 |      |          <-- valor/referencia
```

#### Função

Quando você gera um função, as variaveis que você cria como parametro geram uma possição
na memoria, se eles não forem do tipo referencia, ela aguardam para recebem um valor, se 
forem do tipo referencia pegar a referencia da variavel passada.

```
function teste($a){

}

 0080 | 0081 | 0082 | 0083 | 0084 | 0085 | 0086     <-- possição da memoria
      |      | $a   |      |      |      |          <-- alias
      |      |      |      |      |      |          <-- valor/referencia

teste($var);

 0080 | 0081 | 0082 | 0083 | 0084 | 0085 | 0086     <-- possição da memoria
      |      |  $a  |      |      |      |          <-- alias
      |      |   5  |      |      |      |          <-- valor/referencia


function teste(&$a){

}

 0080 | 0081 | 0082 | 0083 | 0084 | 0085 | 0086     <-- possição da memoria
      |      | $a   |      |      |      |          <-- alias
      |      |      |      |      |      |          <-- valor/referencia

teste($var);

 0080 | 0081 | 0082 | 0083 | 0084 | 0085 | 0086     <-- possição da memoria
      |      |  $a  |      |      |      |          <-- alias
      |      | 0052 |      |      |      |          <-- valor/referencia
```

Assim `$a` dentro da função altera o local da memoria `0052`, alterando o conteudo definitivamente.

Comment: Explicação melhor seria impossível, obrigado.

Comment: @RafaelAcioly Obrigado :D

Comment: O último exemplo não seria `teste(&$var);`? Lembrando que o PHP proibiu passagem por referência no momento da chamada, do lado de quem chama.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert Eu tinha entendido mal seu exemplo, agora entendi direito e vou excluir os comentários aqui. Esse erro que você viu foi exatamente o que eu disse que o PHP proibiu.

Answer (score 3):

Funções onde os parâmetros tem um `&` significa que você deve passar uma variável com um valor simples não funciona. Passagem por referência significa que a variável passada terá seu valor alterado pela função, se ela for destruida dentro da função e você fizer algumação ação nela após a execução, um erro será gerado.

```
function foo(&$var) {
   $var++;  
}
foo(5);//erro.
```

Passagem de argumento por valor significa que variável ou valor passado será copiada para função e seu 'original' continuará sem modificações.

Exemplo 1

```
function porReferencia(&$arg){
    $arg = 'modificado por referência';
}

$argOriginal = 'original';
referencia($argOriginal);
echo $argOriginal; //modificado por referência
```

Exemplo 2

```
function porValor($arg){
    $arg = 'modificado por valor';
    return $arg;
}

$arg = 'original';
porValor($arg);
echo $arg; //original
```

Com algumas exceções, uma função deve apenas modificar os valores passados como argumento(cópia) e suas variáveis internas e não variáveis fora de seu escopo(globais), as alterações devem ser retornadas, dessa forma não se perde o conteúdo original caso seja necessario usa-lo ou compara-lo como no exemplo 2

Em outras linguagens é possível montar um exemplo interessante onde você passar uma variável ou objeto para um função/método e dentro dela destroi o a referência, depois da chamada tenta acessar essa variável e um erro geral dizendo que o identificar nunca existiu.

Comment: mas e se eu colocar uma variável antes da função e mudar o valor dela depois da função, qual o valor sera considerado para mudança?

Comment: @RafaelAcioly, a edição responde o seu comentário?

Answer (score 1):

Levei anos para entender porque sempre evitei usar e também por não entender o uso prático em situações reais. E também por não ter tido interesse.

Eu sempre via exemplos com parâmetros em funções `function foo(&$var) {` mas eu não compreendia o motivo de usar isso pois posso fazer usando `global` ou propriedade estática de uma classe.

Há alguns anos atrás vi um exemplo de uso muito diferente e simples, usando array. Aquilo me despertou interesse em entender o uso desse recurso de parâmetros por referência.

O exemplo com array que vi foi algo como isso:

```
    $arr = array(0 => 'a', 1 => 'b', 2 => 'c');

    print_r($arr);

    /*
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
)

    */

    $foo = &$arr[0];
    $foo = 'a modified';

    print_r($arr);

    /*
Array
(
    [0] => a modified
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
)

    */
```

Veja como o `$foo` passa a agir como uma referência ou seja, como um atalho (alias) do array que recebeu na sua declaração.

Qualquer coisa que `$foo` receber, será "espelhado" diretamente em `$arr[0]`.

Isso facilita muito na manipulação de arrays multidimensionais.

Há outros usos diversos, conforme citado nas outras respostas.

Quando pensar em atribuições por referência, sempre imagine uma variável "fake" onde o valor é meramente um link no endereço de memória, ou seja, um alias (atalho).